# installing javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, pagination, jquery-pagination

im trying to set up a pagination plugin, one that does not load the entire page, only refreshes the content. the plugin i found at http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#example-full is looking spot on. (correct me please if thats not what i was trying to explain before LOL) looks simple and all. but i just dont know where to put the codes. i already placed the .js file under js folder on the bootstrap main folder. and i understand you put a script tag on the index but then thats where im at. and another thing. do i still need to make a bunch of htmls for when the content changes? and thats all :D thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **bootpag** website's main page (http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#example-full). Under the first section, **Installation**, there's the **Getting Started** one, in which you can find all the information you need; there's also some code that the developers of this plugin wrote to explain you how to basically set up a webpage that uses their plugin. You first prepare an empty `html` element which should contain **pagination** (*bootpag* will create pagination list). 
After page load init *bootpag* with number of total page pages `$('.my-element').bootpag({total: 15})`.
From now on you can listen for page changes `$('.my-element').on("page", function(event, num){})`.
Go to the link I wrote, and you will find a complete example of what you need to do, plus the overall **Documentation** and clear examples.

Comment: i think its got to work. but just to clarify this, if i want to add more content, where do i put it? should i just keep adding more code so bootpag gets on its way of making the list? and where exactly will i see the $('.my-element').bootpag({total: 15}) ? on css? thats where i put the "source" ?

Comment: ok this is where im at. i have put script tag below the head. then the dynamic content (codes for youtube videos) then pagination code where it should be. and then the init bootpag after those two. what if i want to show only 3 videos per page? also the empty html should be linked to index?